# print out data from mysql

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, database

i am trying to print out data from mysql into python but it doesn't work

```
cursor=cnx.cursor()
query='select * from test order by Age asc;'
a=cursor.execute(query)
for (Name,Last_name,Home_number,Age,Gender) in cursor:
    print(a)
cnx.close()
```

but it prints (None)
any idea how to fix it?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? If you want to print out data, why do you use `print(a)`?

Comment: because a =cursor.execute(query)

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it